# My spring boot application will automatically saved the input form after session time out and append to new one

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot

I have created a submit form in html like this, in order to add a new project to database, no other javascript or ajax code involved in here. I didn't use any frontend framework as well.

Just this submit form:

```
<form action="addProject" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label mb-1">Project Title</label> 
            <input id="project-title" name="project-title" type="text" class="form-control" aria-required="true" data-val-required="Please enter project title" aria-invalid="false" required>                                      
        </div>
<form>
```

And when the user gets session timeout and then he/she submit this form, the system will lead them to login page, and their previous work will not be saved. The Controller, the database will not save their work either. That's all reasonable.

But when they open the create project page again and try to submit a new project, the previous unsaved work will automatically append to their new work!!

For example, I created a project named "1111", and session timeout, I didn't save it. Then I create a new project called "2222", and submit it, the project title saved in database will be called "2222,1111".

That's super weird!!!

All the js libraries I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/prism/prism.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="assets/plugins/jquery-scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="assets/plugins/stickyfill/dist/stickyfill.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="assets/plugins/jquery-confirm/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="assets/plugins/editormd/editormd.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript"
    src="assets/plugins/animsition/animsition.min.js"></script>
```